# How to combine GZip + CDN for faster page loads?

Tags: php, cdn, page-speed, lamp, gzip

I made a Speed Test on my site via online tool. The tool recommended enabling compression to speed up the site. As far as I understand this requires some changes on server (already done by hosting support) and making some entries into .htaccess file. I searched internet and there are many different recommendations about what to enter into .htaccess file.I am just a bit scared to screw things with wrong entries. does anybody know how to implement this method.
Thanks